A Challenge with Docker compose on a Spring boot + mysql application
I am trying to deploy my springboot application + mysql online
I have tried several things and this is the latest in a line of frustrating attempts. (my aws account is already having issues and customer support has not been worked out there)
I have created a docker file, created my docker compose file, I have successfully ran "docker-compose build", but on running "docker-compose up", I keep getting a series of unforgiving errors, that i am struggling to debug or understand, as the code runs successfully without docker compose.
I would appreciate any help, because I need to dockerize it with docker compose before hosting on render or railway.
PS: I have submitted this question before, it was closed and I resubmitted after editing, but my edited submission has not been reviewed for over a week.
I tried to use docker compose to containize and deploy my springboot + mysql application, I expect the application to run successfully so i can deploy it on render or railway or etc
Here is the error message that I am getting.
springboot-app-1 | java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
My Docker file

# base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

# volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# JAR file
COPY target/bookville_2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

# Expose the port 
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

My Docker compose file
version: '3.8'

services:
  springboot-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dbname
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.33
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bookville
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql-data:

My application.properties
spring.application.name=bookville
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/bookville
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


It might be a timing issue where your app tries connecting to the database before it's ready. Try replacing your ENTRYPOINT with ENTRYPOINT sleep 10 && java -jar /app.jar.

Thanks for taking the time to reply. I tried to solve the timing issue by:
Starting the database using docker compose up -d mysql and then after a short while, I ran docker compose up -d to start the rest of my containers.
I got the same errors.

does the spring boot container know what dns entry mysql is.
